# Workbench: Allow users to publish revisions without moderation

Tags: workflows, workbench

I want to be able to moderate authors who create new nodes, but allow authors to update their existing nodes without moderation. It's not immediately obvious to me how to do this in Workbench.

It seems like I should be able to set up a Rule that will basically have

Event: After updating existing content

Condition: Content's current moderation state is published

Reaction: Set moderation state during save: Published

Something like that. I've tried a lot of combinations, but I can't get it to work.

Also, every time an author saves, it saves as a Draft, which I almost never want. Even though the Default State is set to Needs Review that only applies to new nodes. Revisions of existing nodes are always saved as drafts.

So ideally what I'm trying achieve is this

- new nodes default to Needs Review
- revisions of existing nodes default to Publised

Comment: This may just be a limitation of the workbench moderation module: https://drupal.org/node/1408858

Comment: Another related issue: https://drupal.org/node/1147646

Comment: The basic problem seems to be that the Workbench module is hardcoded to save new revisions as drafts, so the default state only works on a node creation. Still, it seems like I should be able to do something with Rules that would push it to the states I need in spite of the defaults.

Comment: thank you, I searched for this answer for a lot of time!!

Comment: I need the same thing but could not find any solution

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of bizarre and I'd love to hear other answers, but after much trial and error with Rules, it turns out this seems to work with the following setup:

Event: After updating existing content [so it's not a new node]

Condition: Content is published [so admin has approved it at least once]

Reaction: 
1. Publish Content
2. Set moderation state during save: Published

I would have thought that *either* #1 or #2 would have been sufficient, but strangely if they are not combined, it always reverts to draft. Also strange, the order doesn't seem to matter. I've had it working #1 then #2 and #2 then #1.

Comment: i have both #1 and #2 but it always go to draft(current)?